# Condição PHP com ID

Tags: php

Sou um pouco novato nessa área, mas vou fazer a minha pergunta da mesma forma e tentar me explicar o melhor que posso.

Eu tenho uma tabela no banco de dados mysql, que tem id e nome e status

Eu queria fazer uma condição php que verificasse uma tabela no banco de dados e me mostrasse o resultado com o menor id. Ou seja, uma tabela tem vários registos, como id 4, 5,6, 7 etc...

O PHP varia uma verificação e de todos os registos mostrava-me o que tivesse o menor id.

Comment: Mostrar um pouco do seu código ajudaria a entender melhor seu estágio atual.

Answer (score 2):

Para isto, existe a função *MIN()* do *SQL*, que retorna o menor valor, veja:

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM tabela;
```

Para uma consulta, utilizando o *PHP*, terias algo assim:

```
$conexao = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario_do_banco", "senha_do_banco", "banco_de_dados");
if($conexao){
  $consulta = "SELECT MIN(id) FROM nome_da_tabela";
  if($resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $consulta)){
    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
         echo $linha["id"] . "<br/>";
         echo $linha["outro_campo_nesta_tabela"] . "<br/>";
         ...
    }
  }
}
```

As consultas *SQL* com o *PHP* são algo simples, sendo que não irei explicar, o resto. Existem já várias *perguntas* relacionadas a conexão com o banco de dados, e já foram respondidas.

---

## Referências:

[SQL MIN()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_min.asp)

[MySQLi - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: No caso como adaptaria ao php?

Comment: Para adaptar, tens antes de saber conectar ao _MySQL_.

Comment: essa resposta eh o suficiente.. Gonçalo.  se quer saber como usar o script, acho que o problema está mais embaixo. Deve começar a pelo be-a-ba do PHP